# Mysql Trigger Error with IF THEN

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a problem with trigger.. I would like to change a value to false if new returnBike is not null.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER returnBikeTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW
    IF (NEW.returnBike <> null) THEN
        UPDATE Bike SET isRented = false
        WHERE id = (select Bike from Rent); -- but there is Error (missing semicolon)
        END IF;
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is this trigger is right? You are comparing id = (select Bike from Rent) which seems wrong.

Comment: Also you can't use the `<>` operator for `NULL`.  You want `IF(New.returnBike IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: In my triggers before this where comparing was good. Still there is a problem with syntax about missing semicolon - when I use IF/THEN for my trigger

Comment: Okey, for this scenario there was a problem with END $$ and DELIMITER $$
Im trying use trigger to update another table if update on first table.

Comment: (1) include your whole create; neither `END $$` nor `DELIMITER $$` are shown in your question. (2) `X = (SELECT Y from Z)` expressions only work if Z has a single row; wouldn't something like `WHERE id = NEW.returnBike` or `id = NEW.Bike` be more succinct and appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to just do:

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE TRIGGER returnBikeTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Bike
        SET isRented = false
    WHERE id = new.Bike AND NEW.returnBike IS NOT NULL;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: RIght, I could exclude 'if' and just use the same in 'where' parameters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE TRIGGER returnBikeTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.returnBike IS NOT NULL) THEN
        UPDATE BikeSET isRented = false
        WHERE id = new.Bike;
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

so to remove problem with syntax semicolon added delimiter and $$ after end;
Anyway thanks to give me some advice with if, comparing!